# Gitlab prevent user push from certain IPs

Tags: git, gitlab

Gitlab community edition 13.12.15.
I would like to prevent users to push from devices in one network segment. Current approaching strategy is to use pre-receive hook and reject push if some IP detected.

I follow [this guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html?tab=GitLab+15.10+and+earlier) and successfully setup the server hook, however I have trouble obtaining IP of the use try to push. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a public repo where anyone can push? If no, what's the use case for this? Typically you use authentication to control *who* can push, instead of from where.

Comment: It's an internal repo. We want to block users to push from devices in one network segment. They can view and pull or push from other devices, but the machine in that particular network segment shall be in read only mode.

Comment: Right. I understand *what* you're trying to do, but I'm curious about *why* you wish to prevent a user who can push from one place, to not be able to push from another place. I'm asking because this feels like it could be an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248209).

Comment: BTW, based on the answer to the *why*, if it turns out you are able to use *who* instead of *from where*, then you could have machines in the network segment authenticated with Guest users, instead of Developer users. Then the [GL permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) will handle it for you without a custom hook.

Comment: Those devices are in a closed network. Users request us to open Gitlab access for development purposes, however, we want to ensure that user doesn't take out any confidential data through gitlab. We can't authenticate by user as they will work through different machines. Unfortunately. :(

Comment: OK, If I understand correctly: Users login to these devices with their regular user accounts. They want (or need) to have access to the GL repo while they are using these devices. Is it the case that the devices in the closed network have access to confidential data that is **not** currently in GitLab, and you wish to prevent users from copying that data into the local repo and pushing it into GitLab?

Comment: Yes, that's the scenario.

Comment: One possible workaround might be to mirror the main repo, let the isolated network access the mirror but not the main repo, and give all the users only Guest access to the mirrored repo.

Comment: I was thinking about reading IPs from gitlab-shell.log / gitlab-access.log, but your solution might be better.